# Docker command not found when using phpseclib

Tags: php, docker, phpseclib, laravel-5.5, docker-for-mac

I'm experiencing an error when locally ssh connected to my machine and executing 'docker ps' (or any other docker specific command). This issue is only related to docker command. Every other command work like a charm.

```
$ssh = new SSH2('127.0.0.1');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
// after succesfull login

echo $ssh->exec('docker ps'); // or any other docker command (error here)
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

Executing code above, the first echo return `zsh:1: command not found: docker`, while second echo return correct information.

My setup is:

Laravel v5.5.19

phpseclib v2.0.7

macOS High Sierra 10.13 (17A405)

Docker for Mac: version: 17.09.0-ce-mac35

**Update**

I think the issue is the **mac itself**(and r**emote login**?).
The same code above on Windows 10 connecting to Ubuntu 16.4 server work flawlessly. The mac connecting to Ubuntu server works, but mac connecting to himself (localhost), then the issue appears.

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but this time return `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified `. I have only one account on this machine which I use for ssh into the machine via Sharing->Remote login.  With terminal, I never had to use `sudo`.

Comment: And you can run `docker` commands on the command line of the machine?

Comment: Yes, I can. This issue only occurs when executed with the code above. I can normally use `docker` without changing anything or using `sudo`.

Comment: Try it with passthru http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: It does work, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve. It should be executed via ssh command, connected to the server(in this case, my mac).

Comment: SSH is not what executes the command, `exec()` or `passthru()` is.

Comment: If you need a TTY / PTY try `$ssh->enablePTY()`. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html for more info

Comment: I already tried with that, and the result is `1` (one). Which doesn't mean anything.        **$ssh->enablePTY();**
        echo $ssh->exec('docker ps');
        dd('end');

Comment: When you use `$ssh->enablePTY()` `exec` just returns a boolean. You need to do `$ssh->read();` to get the output. The reason it behaves this way is because with `$ssh->read();` (unlike `$ssh->exec()` without a PTY) you can send stuff to the server as the server is sending stuff to you. You can't do that with `$ssh->exec()` normally.

Comment: Using `$ssh->read();` after  `$ssh->exec()` result again in `zsh:1: command not found: docker`. This is somehow specific to docker only issue. Every other command like `$ssh->exec('top')` can be executed without using `$ssh->enablePTY()`.

Comment: Well I do note you're using zsh. I'm guessing that's the shell that's in your `/etc/passwd` file for your user? idk too much about zsh but I know bash has a `.bashrc` file. Maybe zsh has something similar. idk if that file or it's analog would be ran if you did `$ssh->exec()` with a PTY tho. Maybe you need to do full on interactive commands. eg. `$ssh->read('[prompt]')` and then `$ssh->write("docker ps\n");`